# Text roller left to right animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I am creating a moving bar with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. The problem is that the bar does not move left to right.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("text-roller");
  var text_roller = new TextRoller(element);
  text_roller.start();
});

var TextRoller = (function() {

  //Helper functions
  function getWidth(element) {
    var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.right - rect.left;
  }

  function TextRoller(box, speed = 20) {
    var inner_element = box.children && box.children[0] || null;
    if (!inner_element) throw "No child node found";

    inner_element.style.position = "relative";

    this.position = 0;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.box_width = getWidth(box);
    this.inner_element_width = getWidth(inner_element);
    this.box = box;
    this.inner_element = inner_element.cloneNode(true);
    setUpChildrens.call(this);
  }

  //Private functions
  function refreshWidths() {
    this.box_width = getWidth(this.box);
    this.inner_element_width = getWidth(this.box.children[0]);
  }

  function calculateNumElements() {
    return 1;
  }

  function setUpChildrens() {
    var qty = calculateNumElements.call(this);
    if (qty > this.box.children.length) {
      for (var i = this.box.children.length; i < qty; i++)
        this.box.appendChild(this.inner_element.cloneNode(true));
    } else if (qty < this.box.children.length) {
      for (var i = qty; i < this.box.children.length; i++)
        this.box.removeChild(this.box.lastChild);
    }
  }

  function nextFrame(delta) {
    var self = this;
    refreshWidths.call(this);
    setUpChildrens.call(this);
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.box.children, function(el) {
      el.style.left = -self.position + "px";
    });
    this.position += this.speed * delta / 300;
    if (this.position >= this.inner_element_width) this.position = this.position % this.inner_element_width;
  }

  TextRoller.prototype = {

    start: function() {
      this._running = true;
      var self = this;
      var last_time = null;
      var loop_func = function() {
        if (!self._running) return;
        var now = Date.now();
        var delta = last_time === null ? 0 : now - last_time;
        nextFrame.call(self, delta);
        last_time = now;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop_func);
      };
      window.requestAnimationFrame(loop_func);
    },

    stop: function() {
      this._running = false;
    }

  };

  return TextRoller;
})();
```

```css
#text-roller {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #88191d;
  color: black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.swiper-wrapper {
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.swiper-wrapper div h2 {
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="text-roller">
  <div class="swiper-pointer-events">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Interaction</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Element</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 6% ;">
        <h2>DIgital SOlution</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Strategy</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Branding</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Agency</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Interaction</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 6% ;">
        <h2>DIgital SOlution</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Development</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Studio</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Strategy</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Branding</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Agency</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>typhography</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Design</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Interaction</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Element</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 6% ;">
        <h2>DIgital SOlution</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Strategy</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Branding</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Agency</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Interaction</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 6% ;">
        <h2>DIgital SOlution</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Development</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Studio</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Strategy</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Branding</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Agency</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>typhography</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Design</h2>
      </div>
      <div style="width: 4% ;">
        <h2>Interaction</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Developer_pro/pen/ZEqxpyV)

Comment: Please add your code directly to the question.

Comment: instead of giving negative `left` position, make this positive and update your repeat logic

Comment: https://codepen.io/Developer_pro/pen/ZEqxpyV

Comment: @MadanBhandari I do all things but not work